# Nexmo restricted to sent messages globally

Tags: vonage

Currently, I am using a Test account to sent the messages and It is restricted me to sent the messages to only added numbers. I have to send messages globally to any number. How can I do this? Will this allow me to sent messages globally If I use a paid account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When initially creating a Nexmo account you will be given €2 welcome credit.
At this stage, you are able to use our products on up to 10 destination numbers of your choice managed on the test numbers page and the text [FREE SMS DEMO, TEST MESSAGE] will be added to all SMS you send.

To enable full account features you will need to add credit to your account and make your first payment.

Once this is done you no longer need to:
Whitelist your destination numbers
Have the message [FREE SMS DEMO, TEST MESSAGE] attached to your SMS
(note: older accounts that have not yet made their first payment have the shorter wording [Nexmo DEMO] attached to SMS, instead of [FREE SMS DEMO, TEST MESSAGE]

Comment: Thanks, @izapz now I understand the functionality but I need some more clarification:
1.  Is paid account allowed to send messages on to the DND activated numbers?

2. Sometimes messages are not delivered to the end users, is it caused because of I am using Trial API key? and if I take paid API key then it will resolved or not?

Comment: @Rahul , You're not allowed to send SMS to any number as in different countries there're different rules. For example here are example restrictions: 

**For USA:** https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204017023-USA-SMS-Features-Restrictions

**For India:** https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204017423-India-SMS-Features-Restrictions

So, if you're not violating any rule, your SMS should be delivered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am using paid account and it allows me to send global messages.